# AUC test statistic S and p-value in R

Tags: r, roc, auc

I have a dataframe like this:

```
> df
    obs pred
1    0    0
2    1    0
3    0    0
4    1    1
5    0    0
6    0    0
7    0    1
8    1    1
9    0    1
10   0    0
11   1    0
12   1    1
```

where `obs` is the observed result and `pred` is the predicted result of my binary model. By the function `roc` of the `pROC` package I have got an AUC = 0.6626. Given an original AUC = 0.75 I should calculate the test statistic S and the p-value. This is somehow connected to the Mann-Whitney U statistic, but I don't really know how to proceed to get S and the p-value.

Comment: ??'mann-whitney' leads you to this help page "wilcox.test {stats}  
Wilcoxon Rank Sum and Signed Rank Tests  
Description:
Performs one- and two-sample Wilcoxon tests on vectors of data; the latter is also known as ‘Mann-Whitney’ test." However you don't have the proper dataset for MW or two-sample Wilcoxon, since they assume continuous outcomes. You have categorical outcomes. You need statistical advice before continuing.

Comment: What does "original AUC = 0.75" mean?